# Как можно уменьшить время получения запроса

Tags: php

Использую api кинопоиска для вывода рейтинга фильмов с сайта вот [отсюда](http://docs.kinopoiskapi.apiary.io/#reference/0/0)  в реализации php вот собствено код

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.kinopoisk.cf/getFilm?filmID=714888
");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$querys = json_decode($response);
$star=$querys->ratingData->rating;
$IMDd=$querys->ratingData->ratingIMDb;
```

и если на странице с одним запросом это работает быстро все хорошо то на странице категорий где таких запросов может быть много все работает куда как медленней. Записывать в базу не выход рейтинги могут меняться очень быстро(что актуально для вновь снятых фильмов). Посоветуете как можно ускорить работу с api?

Comment: Нужно параллелить. PHP для этого не подходит. Я бы рекомендовал js либо java

Comment: @rjhdby если бы мог использовать js поверьте использовал.

Comment: curl умеет работать "многопоточно". То есть, ему можно дать десяток урлов и он их будет в параллель загружать. И если сервис с той стороны готов так отдать, то будет действительно быстро. Другое дело, что сервису подобные нагрузки могут не понравиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу сказать одно, что подобный подход является критичным к проектированию функционала. Вы по сути опираетесь в Live режиме на сторонний ресурс, который не обязан быть доступен всегда.

Я бы в вашем случае изначально задумался о кэшировании полученных данных из API в какое-то временное хранилище (например Memcached) со сроком от 1 до 24 часов.

Важна ли Вам разница в рейтинге в 24 часа или разница в рейтинге в 15 минут? Я думаю нет, за-то производительность вашего источника данных будет в сотни раз быстрее получения данных из стороннего источника. Минимальный плюс кэширования здесь даже в том, что когда стороннее API "ляжет", ваш ресурс продолжит работать в обычном режиме. Также одинаковые запросы пользователей не будут создавать дополнительную нагрузку на стороннее API - перегружая сеть одинаковыми запросами.

Ускорить вашу программу можно также с помощью воркеров и очередей, у Вас есть очередь заданий, и подключенные воркеры которые смотрят за очередью, как только нужно обновить рейтинг фильма, вы отправляете задание в очередь и воркеры записывают значение в какое-то временное хранилище, после чего вы показываете пользователю рейтинг. Плюс в том, что можете добавить столько воркеров, в зависимости от требуемой производительности и они будут работать параллельно. Это некоторый аналог многопоточности для клиента.